# How do I update textfield2 based on editing textfield1?

Tags: ios, swift, addtarget

I like to update textfield2 as soon as totalAmount has been edited, I am trying the following:

```
    totalAmount.addTarget(self, action: "changeTextField2:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEndOnExit)

 func changeTextField2(textField: UITextField) {
        print("Total amount: \(totalAmount.text)")
        //amount vat - calculate vat based on textField
        amountVAT.text = "88"
    }
```

And i am saving the text field values with

```
func newItem(){

    let context = self.context
    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: context)


    let nItem = List(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()

    nItem.amountVAT = numberFormatter.numberFromString(amountVAT.text!)
    .....more values
    nItem.invoiceImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)

    do {
     try context.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
func saveValues(sender: AnyObject) {

        if nItem != nil {
            editItem()
        } else {
            newItem()
        }

        dismissVC()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using UITextFieldDelegate Method use this function
1.)

```
textField1.delegate = self
```

2.)

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
   if textField == textField1
   {
      textField2.text = textField1.text
   }
}
```

now its upto you how you change the totalAmount.

Comment: textfield is updated but when i save the new textfield value it stores an empty value?

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the delegate function of `UITextField` 
`- textFieldDidEndEditing:` for your textField1. Once in this function, you can get value of textField1 and you can edit textField2.

[Apple Documentation for UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this `totalAmount.addTarget(self, action: "changeTextField2:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)`

i.e change the UIControlEvents to "EditingChanged"